# Apoyo para entender un proyecto de .net framework 4.5

Tags: visual-studio, .net, .netframework

Estoy intentando realizar un backup de un cliente solo que el trabajo me lo delegaron a mí :/ y yo no tengo idea del entorno de .net. He conseguido subir una de sus aplicaciones a azure y funciona al 100, pero esta nueva está diferente... La primera aplicación que subí era una solución .sln, pero este nuevo archivo que me mandaron pareciera ser una compilación de esta, o no sé... pero he intentado de mil formas que Visual Studio (v2019) lo ejecute y no lo logro... He leído que el proyecto debería contener algún archivo de arranque como Startup.cs pero este no viene en ningún lado. Adjunto imagen del proyecto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería que alguien me explicara qué es exactamente lo que estoy recibiendo, ya que estoy tratando con el cliente y el desarrollador (que es un hindú que cree que le voy a quitar el trabajo xD, pero no es así) y parece que éste último pone muchas trabas para que yo pueda completar este trabajo.

Comment: Parece que es un webforms, crea una solución de ese tipo, pega todo el contenido y agrégalo a la solución. Por otro lado, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. También revisa cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Este último enlace tiene recomendaciones de cómo construir preguntas, el meme de esa publicación es ajeno a tu escenario. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estás enfrentando desafíos al tratar de comprender y trabajar con un proyecto de .NET Framework 4.5, especialmente sin tener experiencia previa en .NET. Aquí te dejo algunos puntos clave que te ayudarán a orientarte:

```
Archivos Fuente (.cs o .vb): Estos son los archivos de código de tu aplicación. Si el proyecto es en C#, buscarás archivos con la extensión .cs. Si es en Visual Basic, serán archivos .vb.

Archivos de Vistas (.asax, .aspx): En proyectos web de .NET, como Web Forms, encontrarás archivos como .asax (Global.asax, que es un archivo de configuración global) y .aspx (páginas web del lado del servidor).

Archivos de Proyecto (.csproj o .vbproj): Estos archivos contienen información sobre la configuración del proyecto, como referencias a bibliotecas y otros archivos necesarios para la compilación.

Archivos de Configuración (App.config o Web.config): Son esenciales para configurar aspectos como la conexión a bases de datos, configuraciones del servidor, etc.
```

En cuanto a Program.cs, es más común en versiones recientes de .NET. En proyectos web como el tuyo, es probable que no necesites un archivo de inicio como tal, ya que el punto de entrada suele ser Default.aspx.

Para confirmar si lo que tienes es una aplicación compilada, revisa la carpeta /bin. Si encuentras archivos .dll directamente allí, es probable que sea una versión compilada. Si, por otro lado, ves carpetas como Release o Debug con archivos .dll dentro, entonces son los archivos fuente. Estas carpetas se generan durante la compilación cuando se está desarrollando.

Espero que esta información te sea de ayuda para avanzar con tu proyecto. ¡Mucho ánimo!